# Is it possible to use @NamedEntityGraph polymorphically in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an application which loads the Profile by using JPA inheritance.

I'm able to load it polymorphically depending on the type, but I would prefer to be able in some situations to load the lazy fields of a specific profile (like "jobs" for Employer).

Is there possible to load the lazy fields using inheritance through @NamedEntityGraph?

Could you recommend a better solution for this situation?

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="profile")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Profile {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employer")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Employer extends Profile {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="employer_id")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private Set<Job> jobs;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Candidate extends Profile {
...
}
```

And the following repo:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepo extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long>{
   Profile findOneProfileByUserId(long userId);
}
```

Comment: why not define a NamedEntityGraph per Entity?

Comment: At the moment, I have a NamedEntityGraph per Entity, but as you can see I would like to let ProfileRep to load the entity in an abstract way. Is it possible to define two @NamedEntityGraphs with the same name (e.q. 'profile.full') for each entity? Would it know to use the specific graph?

Comment: did you solve it